# Stub Authenticator & Stub Content Provider for Google Calendar SyncAdapter - Android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-syncadapter

Do I need to implement Stub Authenticator & Stub Content Provider, if I want to handle sync data of com.android.calendar authority & com.google account types in onPerfomSync method ?

Or will the sync adapter framework recognize that I'm going to use pre-defined by Android Authenticator & Content Provider which already exist...

Comment: have you found an answer for this?

Comment: No, I haven't found any code to implement it in this way. But I've achieved similar approach in usage of ContentObserver, which listens all updates that comes from any calendar, linked with all registered in my devices accounts... so, with this solution, you are not able to enable / disable sync in Settings.